# Boolean return; don't know how to return result I want

Tags: java, boolean

I'm working on a PW verification. I found a code developed by another user here and am using it (user: Quirliom). My problem is if the PW meets all requirements, it spits 1: PW verified. If not, it spits -1: PW not verified. In the boolean method using the code, if I state return true, whether the PW entered by user meets requirement of not, it will state PW meets requirement. How can I change it so if it meets requirement, true will come and if not, it will be false?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.String;
import java.lang.Character;

public class Password {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter password: ");
    String password = input.next();
    if (isValid(password)) {
        System.out.println("1: Valid Password");
    } else {
        System.out.println("-1: Invalid Password");
    }
}


//Invoke method for PW verification
public static boolean isValid(String password) {

    //Checks if PW is at least 8 characters
    boolean isAtLeast8 = password.length() >= 8;//Checks for at least 8 characters
    if(!isAtLeast8)System.out.println("Must be 8 or more characters.");

    //PW cannot exceed 24 characters
    boolean isAtLeast24 = password.length() <= 24;
    if(!isAtLeast24)System.out.println("Must not exceed 24 characters.");

    //Checks if PW is only letters and digits - no special characters
    //Checks at least one char is not alpha numeric
    boolean hasSpecial = !password.matches(".*[!@#$%^&*].*");
    if(!hasSpecial)System.out.println("Must not contain special character !@#$%^&*.");

    //Check PW to have 2 uppercase
    boolean hasUppercase = !password.equals(password.toLowerCase());
    if(!hasUppercase)System.out.println("Must have 2 uppercase Character");

    //Check PW to have 2 lowercase
    boolean hasLowercase = !password.equals(password.toUpperCase());
    if(!hasLowercase)System.out.println("Must have 2 lowercase Character");

    //Check PW to have 2 digits
    boolean hasNumber = password.matches(".*\\d.*");
    if(!hasNumber)System.out.println("Must have 2 digits");

return true;
```

}

}

Comment: `return false` if any requirement fails?

Comment: I used what @Bohemian suggested. if I return false, it will print invalid even if all requirements of PW is met.

Comment: Not if you `return` _when one fails_.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you want this:

```
return isAtLeast8 && isAtLeast24 && hasSpecial && hasUppercase && hasLowercase && hasNumber;
```

Comment: TY! First time working with Boolean and couldn't figure it out! I have another question. I'm trying to loop so that when the user is done, it'll ask if they want to enter in another PW. I did a do-while loop in the main, but it's not working. Any ideas?

Comment: @user3743409 I'd consider posting another question